# How to modify memory limit in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, memory, debian

I have a project developed in Symfony. I try to a get a specific page then I get a memory limit error. Even If my PHP (7.1) installed version have (-1 no memory limit).

[image]

And here is the error.

[image]

I've tried to delete the cache and I've tried some solutions but nothing of this work for me.

Comment: there's the possibility that there is an error in the script causing the error. Possibly in the PDOStatement.php on line 142?

Comment: Create a phpinfo(); file inside your symfony project. Check the limit there to be sure its -1 and it seems like you are trying to print a Association Mapping entity (like OnetoMany). This will also result in a exhausted memory even if its -1